# Does the concept of Axis Mundi imply the idea of a symmetric universe?

Tags: metaphysics, language, ancient-philosophy

In the mythologies of many cultures the universe is thought to have a *center* ( i do not mean the geographical concretisations which are obviously not accurate, i mean the philosophical conception ) that is called *Axis Mundi* ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis_mundi ).

Does this conception of an *Axis Mundi* imply the idea of an universe that is symmetric with respect to this axis ?

Interesting is that in many Indo-European cultures an *Axis Mundi* exists and that there are derivations of PIE language forms like * *h2er-* ( * *h2r-tos* -> Sanskrit: *rta* -> truth,... ) that link an ontological universal order to *spokes of a wheel*, in the sense that only spokes can be existent that ensure that the wheel is perfectly round ( symmetric ) or in other words obey the universal order.

Comment: In 3D geometry the *centre* is the centre of a sphere and a sphere is symmetric (because the centre is defined as a point equidistant from the surface). Having said that, I do not think that the ancient proposers of this mythical conception were interested into the geometrical properties of the cosmos.

Comment: Geometrical forms are of importance in any ancient cultures from Egypt over Europe to India and also in America, see the pyramids, Stonehenge, Medicine Wheels, the Dharmachakra, Mandalas, ... Mandalas are actually mappings of the cosmos

Comment: A [Maṇḍala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandala) "is a square with four gates containing a circle with a center point." So, yes, it is symmetric.

Comment: The center of a Mandala represents the center of the universe, however can this be generalized to other cultures that also know the conception of an Axis Mundi ?

Comment: This seems like a question more appropriate for History or Linguistics SE than for this site. I am not sure we have users with anthropological expertise on ancient mythology and languages to make the requested generalizations.